# Error trying to test rest call inside Mongoose pre save hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm having problems with my tests since in the pre save hook in Mongoose I have a call to a rest service to set a token based on model data.

I'm trying to use nock to make the rest call mock, but nothing happens the test stills with this error:

`Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves`

This is the code inside the pre save:

```js
  if (this.token_id !== undefined) {
    const {data: {token}} = await updateToken(
      this.token_id,
      {this.username, this.password}
    )
    this.token_id = token
    this.username = null
    this.password = null
  } else {
    const {data: {token}} = await createToken(
      {this.username, this.password}
    )
    this.token_id = token
    this.username = null
    this.password = null
  }
```

Here updateToken and createToken returns the axios call (put and post, respectively)
In the test I have something like :

```js
before(done => {
nock('http://localhost:3000/tokens')
      .post('/credentials', data)
      .reply(200, { token: 'sometoken' })
})

it('Should save all the data with the token', async() => {
      await Model.create(ModelFactory.build({
        _id: someId
      }))
})
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error already says what the problem is. If there's `done`, it needs to be called. There's `done` in `before` and it isn't called. Since it isn't asynchronous, there's no need for `done`. It should be:

```
before(() => {
    nock('http://localhost:3000/tokens')
      .post('/credentials', data)
      .reply(200, { token: 'sometoken' })
})
```